# how can we make bar width dynamic in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want a bar width of the tickinterval. In the image the bar should start from first tickinterval 3 to the next tick interval 6 and second should be from 6-9 and so on.
How do we achieve that ?

```
Please use the fiddle link
        https://jsfiddle.net/kxgbhv7y/
```

Comment: Would you attach the code as well?

Comment: @vitkarpov added fiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this will help, pointRange should be 2 times bigger than pointInterval.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `xAxis.tickInterval` and `series.pointInterval` is a solution which you are looking for.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qtxpendf/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 0,
      pointInterval: 3
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 3
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointInterval

Comment: I have update the fiddle according to my question 
https://jsfiddle.net/kxgbhv7y/

i want the bar to start from 0 and end at 3 so that it appear the bar width is of size 3

Comment: @Pri_stack I am not sure if I understood you well, but you want to achieve something like is done here? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tvgq67uy/ https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointWidth

Comment: Yes, pointwidth is something which adjust the bar width , but i want to adjust the bar width such that each bar width is the size of a tikinterval. If you refer the fiddle the first bar width starts from 0 and ends just before 3. I want it to start from 0 and end at 3 exact. Similarly in future if my tickinterval is of size 2 then the bar should start from 0 and end at 2...Is there any mechanism where we can adjust the bar width same as the tickinterval

Comment: @Pri_stack here is a demo with functionality which calculated the distance between ticks and set this value as a pointWidth: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/goajbxd3/. I set the `pointPlacement` to 'between' for better visual effect.